# How to copy oracle dump from ec2 instance to RDS in AWS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have looked and looked and can't seem to find an answer.
I found answers that used perl dbi - I am not allowed to install perl modules on the ec2 instance so those won't work.
I just have the oracle client on the ec2 instance I haven't found a dbms_file_transfer solution that will work.

An impdp from the ec2 to the rds oracle takes forever for a 114 gb file (currently its been running for three days!) If I can get the dump file from the ec2 instance to the rds DATA_PUMP_DIR it should import faster.

Any ideas?

So someone down voted this because I apparently did not specify the 30 or 40 Internet posts I looked at before posting this. There is nothing I have found that does not use the perl DBI that I cannot add to my ec2 instance or requires me to run an oracle instance on the ec2 instance and violate my Oracle licenses.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that when the FULL oracle client was installed on ec2 perl, perl-dbi, and perl-dbd-oracle were all loaded on the server in /oracle/client/perl/
With this knowledge I was able to get the perl scripts to work transferring files from ec2 to the RDS data_pump_dir.